# Get the latest row each group based on max date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to select single from every group where date is max.

I am trying to do with this bellow

```
|NO | effective   | price     |  level_one| level_two
+---+-------------+----------+|+++++++++++|++++++++++++
|1  | 2011-12-01  |  34       |     1     |    2
|2  | 2011-16-01  |  34       |     1     |    2
|3  | 2011-18-01  | 3434      |     1     |    2
|4  | 2011-16-01  | 3554      |     1     |    3
```

Result should be

```
|NO | effective   | price     |  level_one| level_two
+---+-------------+----------+|+++++++++++|++++++++++++
|3  | 2011-18-01  | 3434      |     1     |    2
|4  | 2011-16-01  | 3554      |     1     |    3
```

But result come

```
|NO | effective   | price     |  level_one| level_two
+---+-------------+----------+|+++++++++++|++++++++++++
|3  | 2011-12-01  | 34        |     1     |    2
|4  | 2011-16-01  | 3554      |     1     |    3
```

tried with

```
$price = App\Price::with('others')
    ->orderBy('effective', 'Desc')
    ->groupBy('level_one','level_two')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thats a Very Odd Date format

Comment: This [would make a good research read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql) may even be considered a Dup

Comment: Does `App\Price::groupBy('level_one', 'level_two')->latest('effective')->first()` return correct date?

Comment: Its not give correct @Tpojka

Comment: It means orderBy comes after groupBy has been made. Subquery is needed.

Comment: @codewarrior I don't know how to do this using eloquent, but I know it's possible using raw SQL. You have to have a nested `SELECT` statement and select from that, something like this: `SELECT level_two, MAX(price) FROM (SELECT level_two, price FROM your_table) AS der GROUP BY level_two`

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Problem on your date format. Normally eloquent and mysql use Y-m-d date format.

Use like this:

```
$price = App\Price::with('others')
    ->orderByRaw("DATE_FORMAT(effective,'%Y-%d-%m') DESC")
    ->groupBy('level_one','level_two')
    ->get();
```